# Can I map global variables to a section other than the .data or .bss sections?

Tags: c, embedded

What will happen if I do not map global variables in the `.data` or `.bss` section. When I try to map it in different section other than `.bss` and `.data`, it takes some garbage value.

Can we define other section for global variables other than `.bss` or `.data`?

Comment: Does C give you that choice?

Comment: Can we define other section for Global variables other than .bss or .data?  Sure, as long as you don't need it initialized.  You may need the section to be placed in a writeable segment:)   Talk to your friendly, neighbourhood linker.

Comment: The short answer to what will happen is you might not get the values you expect for those variables when the function/program starts.

Comment: There are no "sections" in the C standard.

Comment: There will be code somewhere in the code base that assigns initial values to .bss and .data when the program starts up. If you put variables in other sections then you'll need to modify that code

Comment: Formally, the C standard does not allow variables with static storage duration to _not_ get initialized. However, it is a very common non-standard extension to leave out the initialization of .data and .bss, most embedded systems have that option. Mostly this is because the people who wrote the C standard didn't have much of a clue about embedded systems, but had RAM-based, hosted UNIX systems in mind.

Comment: Now what you should do when programming embedded systems is therefore to write code which does not rely on that initialization, but that sets all variables through run-time assignment before they are used. Which probably means you have to bring some static variables out into the file scope and other somewhat ugly things. However, safety and portability is more important than program design in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before execution of main(), the memory setup takes place.

In case of embedded environments, the built tools (compiler, linker etc.) often bring code files named "crte" (C runtime environment) which have the code for that. Maybe only if you have special (expensive) contract with compiler manufacturer, otherwise they might not allow you that insight.
That code will fill "bss" section with 0 and "data" section with defined values. Often those defined values are found in non-volatile memory in another section called something like "data.rom", it just gets copied to "data" section.

If you create another section, it will not automatically get that convenient service. Not without special precautions. The result is values which happen to be in memory after power-on. Not a really good random number generator, but pretty unpredictable. That would match your description as "garbage value".

Either find out how to get the crte do that, or do it yourself.
The way to get crte to do that is probably the linker directive file. It should allow configurations for user defined sections. Maybe something like "init0", or "init .rom". The manual should of course define that for your environment.

For doing it yourself (probably a commercially less optimal method, i.e. too risky, too time consuming), "just" make sure that some code is executed which writes values to the section - before accessing the variables for the first time. The linker probably publishes symbols into compiler-visible list of identifiers, like "__linker_section__begin" and "__linker_section__end". Use those to get the memory addresses right.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler, it should be the one that marks that data as .bss or .data and then in your linker script you might not have a choice as to what section they are in, but you certainly have the choice as to where they go, and if you start messing with that you might have to mess with the bootstrap that moves .data to ram (if needed) and zeros .bss.  But at the same time depending on your system and linker script, you might not have to do either (say a ram based binary like for a raspberry pi, and you place .bss before .data with gnu linker, you neither have to move .data nor have to zero .bss because the objcopy to binary will place it right in the image).

What compiler are you using that C defined global variables can be marked as something other than .bss or .data?  And how are you doing that?